# Page Visibility API not working on Chrome OS X when window is minimized

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

According to Google's docs, they have implemented the Page Visibility API.
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility

However from my testing, it appears to not fire the event when I minimized the browser on Mac OSX 10.9.

This is the code I'm testing:

```
document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Full implementation here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wvupJ/

Comment: Perhaps a clue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117082#c5

Answer (score 0):

The page visiblity API is now supported for Mac as well as Windows since Chrome 42 (April of 2015), as noted on [the still open public-facing Chromium bug for this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117082#c5). The real work was apparently done under [case 246844](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246844), which is not accessible to the public (including myself).

Since I can't see the details of the fix, I'm not sure whether it applies to older Macs, but I know from personal experience that it works at least on Mavericks and Yosemite.

Chrome was the last of the major Mac browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) to fully support the page visibility API, so it should soon be safe to rely on the page visibility API for visitors using recent Macs.

The similar public-facing bug for the page visibility API for Linux ([case 293128](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293128)) is unresolved, so any site with a large percentage of visitors using Chrome on Linux should not yet rely too heavily on the page visibility API, however.